# Location monitoring not accurate while app running on the background

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have an iOS app that suppose the get the phone location based on latitude and longitude when certain events happen regardless if the app is on the foreground or the background. 
When the app is in the foreground, I always get a accurate location. 
However when the app is running on the background sometimes I get an accurate location and sometimes is off by a mile or so. Is there anything trick I can use to get a accurate position when app is running on the background?

 Here are portion of my code.

```
var currentLocation = CLLocation()
var locManager = CLLocationManager()
.
.
locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
.
.
currentLocation = locManager.location!
var long = String(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
var lat = String(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
var location = CLLocation(latitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
```

also is there a way to know if the location I am getting is accurate or not?

Answer (score 2):

try use `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`

Comment: kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation helped to a degree. But what I noticed is if the app recently ran on the background, then I get a good location. However if the app is on the background for let say the last 30 mins, then the location is not very accurate. I am thinking maybe it takes time for the GPS to kick in and the app is trying other means to get the location by using the cell tower? Is also possible once the event happens, I wait for for 5 or 10 secs before trying to get the location? Does that help? – borna 3 hours ago

Comment: I think system is always want to save battery power, so you may want calculate something about the location information, if data look normal, so maybe  location is accuracy, otherwise you can wait for 5 or 10 secs.